# How to decode part of an Ajax call QueryString in c#

Tags: javascript, c#

I am encoding the query string in an Ajax call in Javascript using encodeURL() but I can't find a way to then decode it on the serverin c#.

I use `HttpContext.Current.Request["ID"]` to get the parameter values from the query string and in the debugger I can see that `Request.QueryString` is fully encoded but when I try to get the value of a particular parameter it wont Decode.

I have tried using `HttpUtility.UrlDecode(HttpContext.Current.Request["ID"])` but it doesn't appear to decode it. What am I missing?

Or should I be using a completely different way too get the query values?

Comment: Hi Gary. What is the value of the string after the call to UrlDecode?

Comment: Can you please post value that `HttpContext.Current.Request["ID"]` returns?

Comment: Ok Here is an example - This is was I pass in the Ajax Call '&TAGS=%7BURL:kf_zVzvYWuw%7D%7BTITLE:Nick%20Cave%20&%20The%20Bad%20Seeds%20-%20Jubilee%20Street%20-%20Live%20in%20Copenhagen%7D. and on the server when I call HttpContext.Current.Request["TAGS"] all I get back is '{URL:kf_zVzvYWuw}{TITLE:Nick Cave '

Comment: is there any reason why you can't use model binding for the query string?

Answer (score 0):

Ah sorry!!! - sometimes you just need someone else to ask you a question and then you see the answer yourself - on the client I was using encodeURI instead of encodeURIComponent.